# D3.js violin plot not showing up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, violin-plot

Sorry in advance, I am very new to javascript. I am trying to use this code https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/violin_basicDens.html with my own data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Read the data and compute summary statistics for each specie
d3.csv("violinsummary.csv", function(data) {

    // Show the X scale
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain(["2017-09", "2017-10","2018-02","2018-03"])
        .paddingInner(1)
        .paddingOuter(.5);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Show the Y scale
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([80, 100])
        .range([height, 0]);
    svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Features of density estimate
  var kde = kernelDensityEstimator(kernelEpanechnikov(.2), y.ticks(50));


  // Compute the binning for each group of the dataset
  var sumstat = d3.nest()  // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.DATE;})
    .rollup(function(d) {   // For each key..
      input = d.map(function(g) {
          return g.Power;});
      density = kde(input);   // And compute the binning on it.
      return(density);
    })
    .entries(data);
  console.log(input);
  console.log(density);

  // What is the biggest value that the density estimate reach?
  var maxNum = 0;
  for ( i in sumstat ){
    allBins = sumstat[i].value;
    kdeValues = allBins.map(function(a){return a[1]});
    biggest = d3.max(kdeValues);
    if (biggest > maxNum) { maxNum = biggest }
  }
  console.log(allBins);
  console.log(kdeValues);
  console.log(biggest);


  // The maximum width of a violin must be x.bandwidth = the width dedicated to a group
  var xNum = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, x.bandwidth()])
    .domain([-maxNum,maxNum]);

  console.log(sumstat);

  // Add the shape to this svg!
  svg
    .selectAll("myViolin")
    .data(sumstat)
    .enter()        // So now we are working group per group
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d){ return("translate(" + x(d.key) +" ,0)") } ) // Translation on the right to be at the group position
    .append("path")
        .datum(function(d){ return(d.value)})     // So now we are working density per density
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("fill","#69b3a2")
        .attr("d", d3.area()
            .x0(function(d){ return(xNum(-d[1])) } )
            .x1(function(d){ return(xNum(d[1])) } )
            .y(function(d){ return(y(d[0])) } )
            .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom)    // This makes the line smoother to give the violin appearance. Try d3.curveStep to see the difference
        )

    });



// 2 functions needed for kernel density estimate
function kernelDensityEstimator(kernel, X) {
  return function(V) {
    return X.map(function(x) {
      return [x, d3.mean(V, function(v) { return kernel(x - v); })];
    });
  };
}
function kernelEpanechnikov(k) {
  return function(v) {
    return Math.abs(v /= k) <= 1 ? 0.75 * (1 - v * v) / k : 0;
  };
}


</script>
```

I believe the part of the code where I am adding the shape to the svg is incorrect. All my console log outputs show the correct data. I also ran console log outputs for the example and my data and the example's data have the same data types throughout.

Data (violinsummary.csv):

```
Power,DATE
89.29,2017-09
89.9,2017-09
91.69,2017-09
89.23,2017-09
91.54,2017-09
88.49,2017-09
89.15,2017-09
90.85,2017-09
89.59,2017-09
93.38,2017-10
92.41,2017-10
90.65,2017-10
91.07,2017-10
90.13,2017-10
91.73,2017-10
91.09,2017-10
93.21,2017-10
91.62,2017-10
89.58,2017-10
90.59,2017-10
92.57,2017-10
89.99,2017-10
90.59,2017-10
88.12,2017-10
91.3,2017-10
89.59,2018-02
91.9,2018-02
87.83,2018-02
90.36,2018-02
91.38,2018-02
91.56,2018-02
91.89,2018-02
90.95,2018-02
90.15,2018-02
90.24,2018-02
94.04,2018-02
85.4,2018-02
88.47,2018-02
92.3,2018-02
92.46,2018-02
92.26,2018-02
88.78,2018-02
90.13,2018-03
89.95,2018-03
92.98,2018-03
91.94,2018-03
90.29,2018-03
91.2,2018-03
94.22,2018-03
90.71,2018-03
93.03,2018-03
91.89,2018-03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.paddingInner` is too large, so the bandwidth is too narrow for the violins to display. A value of 1 means a bandwidth of zero.

If `x.paddingInner` is set to a lower value, for example 0.1, then the bandwidth for the x scale will be wider, so the range for xNum scale will be wider and the violins are viewable.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!